# Tcl unable to open serial port com22

Tags: serial-port, tcl

When I try to open `COM22` which is serial port over USB, Tcl answers me the following:

```
couldn't open "com22": no such file or directory
```

Another program opens that serial port successfully.
What could be a reason for that?
Tcl 8.5, Windows 7

Comment: Documented in the ["Portability issues" section of the `open` command's manual page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/open.htm#M51)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These high-numbered ports don't have equivalent DOS names.  Use `\\.\COM22` instead.

Comment: @olegg, note that you should possibly brace this name if using it as is in Tcl's code to prevent backslashes from being interpreted as escape characters.  That is, use something like `set port [open {\\.\COM22} w+]`

Comment: Also note that //./COM22 will work also and avoids the usual nastiness of backslash characters.